# How does view matrix work?

Tags: opengl

To calculate the look vector for the camera, the method is

`look.x = sin(horizontal angle) * cos(vertical angle)
look.y = sin(vertical angle)
look.z = cos(horizontal angle) * cos(vertical angle)`

why is it calculated like this?

I read from some places where people said that the third column is the forward vector of the view matrix, and also is the vector that points to the -1 z axis of the view matrix. The first two columns are left and up vector of this new reference coordinate. Why is it so?

Comment: It's just one of the many methods to do this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles. Depending on how exactly you want to describe your camera's position and orientation, this method may be appropriate or not.

Comment: For the mathematical "why" this works. well: sine and cosine form what's called an "orthonormal base", i.e. they are perpendicular to each other. Which means that putting a mix of sines and cosines into a transformation matrix will give you a transformation that composed of a series of rotations (rotations are orthonormal). – For "why" it's done exactly that way? Well, that's spherical trigonometry for you. I suggest you take some paper, draw XY, XZ and YZ coordinate systems, with unit circles at the origin, some angle into it and derive which values for x y and z that angle gives.